# Оператор < для указателя на функцию не работает

Tags: c++

```
struct A {};
void f() {}

bool operator <(void (*)(), struct A);

int main() {
    f < A{};
}
```

Почему эта программа [не компилируется](https://godbolt.org/z/EbGdjdecq)?

> error C2059: syntax error: ';'

Comment: `(&f) < A{};`  - потому что f - это не указатель на функцию.

Comment: @Chorkov `f` же может быть преобразовано к указателю неявно

Comment: интересно каким образом собираетесь их сравнивать

Comment: @ARHovsepyan это [mre] для CE, реализация оператора не важна

Comment: Просто поместите `f` в скобки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С 20 стандарта , если после имени функции стоит < то компилятор ожидает имя шаблона. Если взять функцию в скобки, то это укажет компилятору, что фукнция не ожидает шаблона.

Comment: или так : `operator <(f , A{});`